# Exact difference between color scaling in ArrayPlot and MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, visualization, scaling

Can someone enlighten me as to how `MatrixPlot` does its color scaling? I get very different visualizations based on whether I use `MatrixPlot` or `ArrayPlot`. Below are the data and the plots.

```
data = {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
 {0., 0.0793707, 0.0100721, 0.00652364, 0.0104472, 0.00222943, 0.00294053, 0.011748, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.00886974, 0.0661885, 0.0280415, 0.00473723, 0.00644965, 0.00490039, 0.0196713, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.00459279, 0.025313, 0.166435, 0.00267822, 0.00466304, 0.0103765, 0.0375706, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.759806, 0.237817, 0.123468, 0.882945, 0.0937895, 0.0665799, 0.194295, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.115309, 0.515863, 0.387874, 0.0784187, 0.846492, 0.168653, 0.270281, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.0311787, 0.143507, 0.284723, 0.0201661, 0.0460761, 0.745912, 0.457078, 0.}, 
 {0., 0.000873036, 0.00123969, 0.00293495, 0.00060797, 0.00030044, 0.000637651, 0.00935619, 0.}, 
 {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}

ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> True]
MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> True, Frame -> False]
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the top part of the left picture is almost all white and the shades are very hard to distinguish, whereas the same area is much clearer in the right picture. I would like to know whether the scaling function used by `MatrixPlot` is linear or not, and if not, how does it scale the values.

Comment: The Details section of `MatrixPlot`states: `With the default setting ColorFunctionScaling->True, scaling is done based on a mixture of relative value and ranking for each matrix element. The final scaled value always lies between 0 and 1, with scaled value 0.5 corresponding to matrix element value 0. ` Hence, it is distinctly non-linear.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think that's an answer. Unless you believe  we should close this one as contained in the docs (although I think it's better to keep it). I can't vote to close anyway b/c my vote is bonding

Comment: @belisarius Well, it only answers the question whether or not it's linear, not how (at least not reproducible).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a look at the color channel value mapping to the raster output:

```
  data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 50}];
  mp = MatrixPlot[data, Mesh -> True, Frame -> False, 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> True];
  (out = Reverse[Cases[mp, _Raster, Infinity][[1, 1]]]);
  GraphicsRow@(ListPlot[ Transpose[{ Flatten[data], # }]] & /@ 
     Transpose[Flatten[out, 1]])
```

[image]

(* red,green,blue *)

there looks to be some piecewise linear color table.

the sum of the channels:

```
 ListPlot[ Transpose[{ Flatten[data], Total /@ Flatten[out, 1] }]]
```

[image]

you can play with the data range and see the mapping change..

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the "scaling function", not the ColorFunction. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: Its really not clear exactly what he's after, I took it to be more about the *look* of the figure..

Comment: You're right about the non-linearity. Deleting my answer

Comment: @belisarius. Still an interesting thing to show, you ought to update the answer

Comment: I'm experimenting a little more. I will if I arrive at any (valuable) conclusion. Thanks!